# JavaScript text sometimes doesn't load

Tags: javascript, text

I'm using a simple HTML theme, with a countdown: http://tentzone.pt/

But sometimes, that text that appears in the beginning, like being written, doesn't load totally.

The text is:

> "O melhor Carnaval do país Estás preparado?"

But sometimes it doesn't load totally, and sometimes only appears as:

> ""O melhor Carnaval do país Estás prepar"

or something like that.

To be clear, the 1st pic is what is supposed to appear, and the second is what sometimes happen

[image]
[image]

Just an example, sometimes it loads less letters, sometimes it loads more letters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably something to do with adding HTML character-by-character instead of real text and DOM nodes. There is a really easy solution, though: don’t use that effect at all! It’s kind of annoying.

Comment: No other solution than remove?

Answer (score 0):

It looked fine to me in Chrome and IE10.  However, and just from my experience, you have seven setTimeouts in the functions.js file that control the text appearance and at least one of those is operating on multiple elements causing repeated calls.  We'd like to think those operate asynchronously or even synchronously but they don't.  A timed operation using intervals or timeouts can overwrite and even block other timed operations depending on the browser, operating system and available javascript iterations. So when you're adding multiple timed requests to a page, they're never reliable because they're dependent on the browser giving them precedence or even space at all in iteration requests and particularly on mobile devices which heavily restrict available iterations to javascript page requests.

Rather than using multiple setTimeout or intervals, it's far more reliable to restrict our requests to one and perform our animations synchronously within that request.  That's the only reliable process because we know the browser will do all of the requests in each iteration of a single request and with a much faster processor speed.

Answer (score 0):

if you use time functions in javascript, the delay depend from browser, network speed and broadband network, for solution it problems.

you shall use tags to ie for many versions, and geolocation if you server is far from user request(if is ajax request),load  style sheets necesary into same index file, load a validate w3c html [is here](http://validator.w3.org/), verify size file, compress js ,

```
<!--[if IE 10]>
special_setTimeout(brow_ie); //special function that use other setimeout time to load
<![endif]-->


special_delay_location(where_is_me_client_from), //special function that send request
```